# Using Python to extract the first 188-byte packet from MPEG Transport Stream but do not see the sync byte

Tags: python, mpeg

I have the following code in Python:

```
with open("my_transport_stream_file.ts", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read(188)
    print(data)
```

In my mind, I believe I am extracting the first 188 bytes from the file i.e the first transport stream packet. Here's what I get:

```
b'G@\x00\x10\x00\x00\xb0\r\x00\x01\xc1\x00\x00\x00\n\xe0e\x8d,\xa3\xec\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

Whilst this is SUPER exciting because I can see some data, I don't see the **0x47** sync byte that I am expecting to see.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what your error may be, but have you checked if you have a `sync error`, usually the `sync bit` will be missing when there is some error

Comment: I am not familiar with sync error. Are you able to provide a short explanation? Also, would you happen to know what the G@ is at the beginning? If its not Hex, what could it be? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it there, It’s the very first byte.

0x47 is the ASCII code for capital letter G.

Whatever you are using to print that string, prints ASCII characters as is, but converts non printable values (values less than 0x20 and greater than 0x7e) to hex, or another escape code, like \r is 0x0d and \n is 0x0a

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thank you Sir! As always you've been instrumental bro my learning. I'm ever grateful :)