# Using Python to check if first byte of MPEG transport stream is a sync byte

Tags: python, mpeg, transport-stream

I am trying to use Python to look into a transport stream, and read the first byte. Once this is done, I will check if this byte is 0x47 to determine if the transport stream is a valid one.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
with open("my_ts_file.ts", "rb") as file_object:
    byte = file_object.read(1)
    if byte == 0x47:
        print("Found first sync byte")
        print(byte)
    else:
        print("Not a valid Transport Stream")
        print(byte)
```

So if the first byte is 0x47 or not, it should display that.

The issue I am having here is that the output of this code shows:

```
Not a valid Transport Stream
b'G'
```

And as @szatmary pointed out here: [Using Python to extract the first 188-byte packet from MPEG Transport Stream but do not see the sync byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895302/using-python-to-extract-the-first-188-byte-packet-from-mpeg-transport-stream-but/58896700#58896700) the letter G is actually the ASCII representation of 0x47 (Hex).

How can I effectively do a comparison between essentially the same value but are represented two different ways?

Comment: byte[0] should give you it as an integer type which you can compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `0x47` into string representing using `chr()`:

```
with open("my_ts_file.ts", "rb") as file_object:
    byte = file_object.read(1)
    if byte == chr(0x47):
        print("Found first sync byte")
        print(byte)
    else:
        print("Not a valid Transport Stream")
        print(byte)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I stop Python using a representation of Hex but rather keep it as Hex such that I don't need to use chr()?

Comment: `if byte == 'G':`or you are going to convert the read byte to hex: `byte = hex(ord(file_object.read(1)))` and `if byte == 0x47`. In the end it is all the same, just depends on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use bitstring module from python.

---

[image]

Comment: donrt read 188, read 1 until you hit a sync byte. Sometimes I get a partial packet first,

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot.

```
SYNC_BYTE = 0x47

    def find_start(tsdata):
        while tsdata:
            one = tsdata.read(1)
            if not one:
                return False
            if one[0] == SYNC_BYTE:
                return True
```

if you slice bytes or convert them to a list, you get the integer value of each byte.

```
>>>> g = b'G'
>>>> list(g)
[71]

>>>> g = b'G'

>>>> g[0]
71
>>>> g == 0x47
False
>>>> g[0] == 0x47
True
>>>> g[0]
71
>>>> g
b'G'
>>>> 

>>>> 

>>>> stuff = b'Fonzie is the coolest'
>>>> list(stuff)
[70, 111, 110, 122, 105, 101, 32, 105, 115, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 99, 111, 111, 108, 101, 115, 116]
```